# C++とPython　配列の計算結果について

Tags: python, c++, opencv, array

opencvによる画像処理プログラムをC++ → Pythonに書き換えています．
その中で，(120,109,3)の配列の要素ごとの引き算が存在したのですが，この結果が２つのプログラム間で合いません．
それまでの結果は完全に一致しており，（同じ数）-（同じ数）の計算でしかないはずです．

どのようにすべきか，あるいは何がおかしいのかについてヒントを頂けるとありがたいです．
よろしくお願いします．

4/15追記

コードについてですが，srcとsrc2が画像であると考えてもらうようにお願いします．
具体的に何がしたいのかですが，
○C++

```
//src, src2はcv::Mat型
for (int i = 0; i < 3, ++i){ 
    //ここの動作を3回繰り返す
    src = src - src2;
}
```

○Python

```
#src,src2はnumpy.ndarray型
for i in range(3):
    //ここの動作を3回繰り返す
    src = src - src2
```

となっています．ヘッダ関係はopencv2(C++)とcv2,numpy(Python)です．
また情報不足だと感じた部分があればお願いします．

Comment: 計算結果が全然、違うのか? それとも、端数レベルで違うのか?

Comment: @皆様 [be-nice な Q&A をしていきましょう :)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Comment: 残念ながら「srcとsrc2が画像であると考えて」だけでは、十分な説明を得ることは難しいかと思います。C++でもPythonでも`-`演算子は多重定義が可能なので、`src`と`src2`が「画像」という漠然とした言い方では、どの定義が使われているのかはよくわかりません。`src`と`src2`が具体的にどんなデータ型になっているのかがわかる情報を示していただけないでしょうか。また、例において変数`i`がどんな役割を持っているのかもわかりづらいです。何か結果に影響すると思われたのでしょうが、あまりにも簡略化されすぎた現在のコードでは、意図もどう関連するのかも推測しかねます。なお、コードは ``` (バッククオート3つ)だけの行で囲んでやるとコードとして成形された表示になりますので、特にPythonのようにインデントが重要な場合には注意して整形するようにしてみてください。

Comment: これ [OpenCV - cv::Mat と numpy 配列の対応まとめ](http://pynote.hatenablog.com/entry/opencv-cpp-python-array-correspondence) とかで、それぞれのデータの型が微妙に違うとか？　行われる計算にも影響が出てくるとか？　は無いですかね。

Comment: 結局「`cv::Mat`の`-`演算と、`numpy.ndarray`の`-`演算では動作に違いがある」というところに行き着くかと思います。(`cv::Mat`の`-`演算は、単純な「（同じ数）-（同じ数）の計算」ではありません。)もっと要素数が少ない場合の例を作られて、具体的に各要素の値をいじりながら結果を見比べていけば、どんな違いがあるのか見えてくるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 色々とありがとうございます．今のところそこまで大きな誤差でもない上，最終的な結果が近ければどうにかなるのでここは後で検討することにして他の部分の完成を優先させようと思います．また何かありましたら質問させていただきますので，よろしくお願いします．

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。ご質問内容がかなり具体的になってきたので、きちんとした回答の書ける方がご質問を読まれれば、わかりやすい回答を書いてもらえるのではないかと思います。時々は回答がついていないか覗いてみるようにしてください。なお、ご自身で解決できた際には自己回答をお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

自己解決しました。負の値の扱いが問題だったようで、
例えば20から10を3回引くとして、C++では0とし、Pythonでは(255)-10で245のようにするのが原因でした。
そこで、Pythonの演算結果に負の値があればそれを強制的に0に置換するような演算を組み込んだところ、C++の結果と一致しました。

色々とありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

同じ値に対して、２つのプログラムで演算(要素ごとの引き算)する過程を追って行って、プログラムによって違いが生じる直前の演算を特定しましょう。

その演算は同じ値に対して異なる値を返す訳ですから、どこかに差異があるはずです。